# Can't connect external monitor to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-monitor

I bought Lenovo thinkpad t14 amd gen 1 laptop with vega amd ryzen 5 4650 pro and **vega 6 graphics card**. and a new 4k 28inch Samsung monitor. I decided to set up dual boot (Windows + Ubuntu). So I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS alongside Windows 10. But when I plug the HDMI cable in, nothing happens. I can't see any new displays in Settings > displays.

`xrandr` shows me:

```
xrandr : Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen 0: minimum 19290x1080, current 1920x1080, maximum 1920x1080 default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm 1920x1080 77.00*
```

Every time I try to type the `xrandr` command, it outputs the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me in the similar type of situation in HP EliteBook 6930p laptop after update from Ubuntu 18.04.4 to Ubuntu 20.04: Please go to Settings → Displays → Scaling in Fractions → and just switch it on (I left it in starting position 100%). I hope this might help also you.